# CSS: Define width of element by contained image not using JS

Tags: html, css, image, width

It seams I can't find a solution without using JS for this problem:
I need to make a horizontal slider with images and a little text beneath it. All images need to be resized to the same height and auto sized for the width. Below the image is a text which should wrap to multiple lines if the image is to small in width.
The problem: I struggle to have the width of the surrounding element limited to the width of the image (while not knowing the image width). 
The expected result is that all images are next to each other with no spacing (similar to google image search).

I'm using white-space:nowrap on the outer element and display:inline-block on the inner to get the horizontal scrolling. I tried with flex too, but got no difference.

Here's a fiddle of what I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/lobin/awbL80st/

```
`<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="(url)">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      A longer text which should wrap to multiple lines.
    </div>
  </li>
<li>
...`
```

css is

```
ul {
  list-style:none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  width:500px;
  height:240px;
}
li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
}
.pic {
  height:150px;
}
img {
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
.text {
  white-space:normal;
}`
```

Any idea?

EDIT:
Expected result is something like this:[image: Screenshot from google image search.]
Underneath the pics should be the text for each pic wrapping to the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `li` as  `display:table-cell;` and added some JS code to get `width` of the image and set it to the text.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a=$("img");
    var b=$('.text');
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
     $(b[i]).css("width",a[i].width);
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  width:500px;
  height:240px;
}
li {
  display:table-cell;
  width:auto;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.pic {
  height:100px;
  width:auto;
}
img {
  height:100%;

}
.text {
  white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/14/14/24/grass-2312139__340.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
A longer text which should wrap to multiple lines.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/14/23/15/soap-bubble-2403673__340.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
A longer text which should wrap to multiple lines.
    </div>
  </li>  
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/04/19/32/sculpture-2284945__340.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
A longer text which should wrap to multiple lines.
    </div>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Another option without javascript is set the `display:table-cell;` property of `li`, it sets the width of every cell to the width of the max-width image.

Try this if it make sense for you.

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  width:500px;
  height:240px;
}
li {
  display:table-cell;
  width:auto;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.pic {
  height:100px;
  width:auto;
}
img {
  height:100%;

}
.text {
  white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
   
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/14/14/24/grass-2312139__340.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
A longer text which should wrap to multiple lines.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/14/23/15/soap-bubble-2403673__340.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
A longer text which should wrap to multiple lines.
    </div>
  </li>  
  <li>
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/04/19/32/sculpture-2284945__340.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
A longer text which should wrap to multiple lines.
    </div>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be to easy... the image proportions should be preserved and no cropping should occur. So a portrait image is displayed in portrait mode (first and last), and a landscape image in landscape mode. The problem is that I don't know the images size.

Comment: With the help of javascript we can achieve that else we don't get the image size in css,

Comment: Thanks, your second option display: table-cell works - at least half, but it might do it for this application.

Comment: Even in the 1st option you can use `table-cell` as with `inline-grid` we can see the changing of `width` which is not the good UX.

Updated the answer.